# Why does my array of pthread_t pointers cause segfault on pthread_create, but references to pthread_t in the array does not

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pthreads

I want to store `pthread_t`'s in an array like so:

```
pthread_t tThreads[nThreads];
```

Soon after, I iterate over the array with a for loop to start the threads

```
pthread_create( &tThreads[i], NULL, &fn, (void*) NULL);
```

I noticed that I am creating an array of `pthread_t`, using a `pthread_t` object at a particular index, then passing a reference to that `pthread_t` to start a thread. Trying to be clever and to reduce verbosity for myself, I changed `tThreads` to an array of `pthread_t` references

```
pthread_t* tThreads[nThreads];
```

so that I can just create the thread like so

```
pthread_create( tThreads[i], NULL, &fn, (void*) NULL);
```

Problem is that the second method produces a segfault when trying to create the pthread.
What is causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pthread_t tThreads[nThreads]`, you define an array that directly contains `pthread_t`-objects. You can pass (the address) of each such valid object to `pthread_create`.

With `pthread_t* tThreads[nThreads]`, in contrast, you define an array of *pointers* to `pthread_t`-objects but not the `pthread_t`-objects themselves.
Passing such an (uninitialized) pointer (pointing "somewhere" but not to a valid `pthread_t`-object) to `pthread_create` will yield undefined behaviour (e.g. a segfault). You'd need a `tThreads[i] = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t))` before each call.

Comment: Makes sense, tried that and it works either way. Thanks!